# Ignoring zeros in columns

Tags: excel

I want to ignore zeros in a specific column using Percentile function. I was seeking out for the Aggregate function , but it does not work. I have also used the following formula, but it did not work:

```
 =PERCENTILE(IF(D1:D8,0.3),0.3"<>0")
```

Here are data : I do not want to use it as an array

```
30
24
23
12
0
17
15
14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct Aggregate Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(16,6,$A$1:$A$8/($A$1:$A$8<>0),0.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an array formula then you can use a *helper column*.  In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(D1=0,"",D1)
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=PERCENTILE(E1:E8,0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Gary- I knew this method, sorry